# Opengl ES 2.0 Vertex - Which way is more efficient?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have two ways to send two variables to my vertex:

A, Use two attributes to send two variables.

B, Make two variables into one, such as 'Mix=Var1*100+Var2', and only send one attribute 'Mix' to my vertex. And in the vertex code I use some calculation to present 'Var1' and 'Var2'.

I Don't know which way is more efficient(take less time to draw).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know either. (*Hint: profile it to know*)

Comment: Also are the variables scalars or vectors. And if they are vectors, which dimension do they have?

Comment: I think it's just Glfloat.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your bottleneck for some extremely strange reason you could profile the 2 approaches over some large number of iterations to see the difference. You should know that even after getting this result you should consider doing the same test on different devices since the output may change mostly because of different GPUs.

If you do chose to use B approach you should probably input an integer value and instead of multiplying and dividing it by 100 try using bitwise operations as in `Var1<<16 + Var2` for 32-bit integers. That means one value will take the first 16 bits and the other the second 16 bits and these operations are extremely fast.

Since you asked this question it suggests that this operation is not your bottleneck and never will be, you are simply asking because you want your code to be fast. If this is true then do not bother with speed performance of this algorithm but rather ask yourself how your code will be more maintainable. The A approach seems to be much more straight forward, will make the code readable and maintainable so I would choose that one. Besides if you at some point decide that those values will become too large to pack 2 in 1 you will have quite an issue converting code from B to A; If you use A and at the end want an extra performance gain (assuming B is somehow faster) all you really need to do is write those 2 lines of algorithm and comment an extra attribute. So from this perspective you should choose A.